How can I find out if High Frequency Injection (HFI) is being used in a Sensorless BLDC motor?
I have a small BLDC sensorless motor that runs  at 34 V DC, reaches 40K RPM, has low resistance(5 ohms) between its phases.
Its own driver manages to run this motor at really low speeds, 1K RPM, at constant speed with really good torque.
Using some other drivers to drive the same motor, I can't even get to this small speeds, so these other drivers seem to not sense the Back-EMF to keep driving this motor at slow speeds.
I tried a lot of drivers, assembled some with Arduino's to do the MOSFETs switching, but I always get to the problem of not being able to run the motor at slow speeds, or when I do, it stalls at the touch of a finger in its shaft, even in speed closed loop. At higher speeds there's no problem, I always can drive the motor with any driver.
So, I suspect its own driver uses some method of HFI to keep the slower speeds stable and with really good torque.
So, is there a way for me to know, maybe by using a scope, if HFI is being used to drive this sensorless motor? If so, how could I wire the scope to the motor and driver, and what should I look for in the scope?
Thanks.
